# What does 炸裂 mean here?

Tags: meaning

> 最終ラウンドでチャンピオンのパンチが炸裂した.　The champion's punch exploded in the final round. (研究社 新和英大辞典 第５版)

Did the punch hit really hard? Did it fail? Please explain what 炸裂 means in the Japanese sentence above, I'm not sure what "the punch exploded" means in English even and google isn't helping either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It hit really hard. I don't know if I can call it an idiomatic phrase, but punches, kicks, and so on can 炸裂 in Japanese.

The typical image of 炸裂 is shown in this video:

https://youtu.be/2yztv5QPp7o?t=1m13s

Answer (score 1):

This is only my speculation so I am not sure it should be written as "My Answer," but...

I guess the writer of the said sentence wanted to convey the meaning "the punch was so hard that it looked exploded." Of course I may be wrong.

Comment: I hate to start a meta-discussion, but...  I suppose someone downvoted my answer because he/she thought it was non-accurate/incorrect etc. As I wrote, that is only my speculation and hence it is prone to error. But If I had written it as a comment to the original post, then our dear Big Brothers would have promptly suppressed it , saying "comments are not for answers." What shall I do?

Comment: (See also http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/25707/what-is-%E3%81%A8-in-this-sentence) Maybe time for a meta discussion on meta?

Comment: Are you saying uncertain answers should only be upvoted? Uncertain answers should go to the place where other people can both upvote and downvote, of course.

Comment: @naruto: <Are you saying uncertain answers should only be upvoted?> How come you came to that conclusion?